# Magento 2 Conflicting component dependencies (Fooman)

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, dependency, conflict

I have a problem while trying to update to Magento 2.1
I'm running 2.0.6 currently, and have updated to this version before without a problem.

Now I'm getting a dependencie error

```
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information



[UnexpectedValueException] 
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(vendor/fooman/packages): failed to open dir: No such file or directory 



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I think it has something todo with a module from Fooman. But I don't understand why, because they were stable up and running till this moment.

I have to solve this problem to continue the update process.

**-------- Edit (14:59 28-06-2016):**

Okay thanks the answer of Kristof and Vinai the above problem has been fixed. But now I'm getting other Dependencie errors also with Foomans modules

```
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0].
- fooman/emailattachments-m2 2.0.3 requires magento/module-sales ~100.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/module-sales[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[100.1.0, 100.0.7].
- fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 2.1.1 requires fooman/emailattachments-m2 ~2.0.0 -    > satisfiable by fooman/emailattachments-m2[2.0.3].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 requires magento/module-sales 100.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-sales[100.1.0].
- Installation request for fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 ~2.1 -> satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2[2.1.1].
```

Comment: We are still in the process of releasing updates that are compatible with 2.1. As this is not yet available your upgrade will be held back. Please email me at support@fooman.co.nz and I'll let you know once the new version is available.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer**
in your Magento root folder run the following command

```
composer config repositories.foomanartifacts artifact $(pwd)/vendor/fooman/packages
```

**Long answer**
We create a local repository for artifacts (i.e. "packages") as part of our installation process. We have now discovered that Magento's upgrade process, only when using the component manager, temporarily changes the composer root directory to the `var` directory during the upgrade process (I don't yet know why they do this). Unfortunately the change of directory means all composer repositories that have been set up using a relative path won't work any more. Running the above command changes the repository to an absolute path to work around this composer root directory change.

Comment: Thanks that problem has been fixed now. But new dependencie errors show up. Also with Foomans modules in it. Could you please check my edit above.

Comment: I also get this error. Above command won't fix it.  `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                                         
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/data/web/magento2/vendor/fooman/packages): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`